# error with notification of a new server to me in private messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

A couple of days ago the code worked, but now it gives an error, please help
`

```py
#оповищение о новом сервере
@client.event
async def on_guild_join( guild ):


    me = client.get_user(404915501727219723)

    emb = discord.Embed( title = f'Я пришел на новый сервер' )

    for guild in client.guilds:
        category = guild.categories[0]
        try:
            channel = category.text_channels[0]
        except:
            channel = category.voice_channels[0]
        link = await channel.create_invite()
    emb.add_field( name = guild.name, value = f"Участников: {len(guild.members)}\nСсылка: {link}" )

    await me.send( embed = emb )
```

`

Now it gives this error, didn't find anything on the internet.
Here is the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6zC7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably occuring because the first category in the guild doesn't have any channels or your bot doesn't have access to it.
I would suggest looping through all channels until you find one that you can create the invite in. Also you would still need a code for the case that there are no channels your bot can create an invite in, so the code would look like this:

```py
link = ""
for channel in guild.channels:
    try:
        link = await channel.create_invite()
    except:
        pass
    else:
        break
if link == "":
    link = "Failed to generate"
```

This should prevent every possibly occuring error

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, the exception is thrown at `channel = category.text_channels[0]` after that the `except` clause was executed. It also throws list **index out of range** error.

The problem is that your `category` list is not populated with any element. I would suggest using a default value if the list has zero elements.

```
channel = category.text_channels[0] if not category.text_channels else YourDefaultInstance()
```

Modify the `YourDefaultInstance()` to correct the class.

Comment: What exactly is Your Default Instance() needed there?

Comment: If the `text_channels` or `voice_channels` have no elements then you need a default value for the `channel`. I do not know the type of the `channel` variable, so I have created an imaginary instance called `YourDefaultInstance()`.